# Hyperledger Fabric plug state database of my choice

Tags: database, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

In Hyperledger Fabric documentation is referred somewhere that state db can be pluggable. At this point levelDB and couchDB are the options as I can see. I want to plug an other database of my choice.Do I have to edit Fabric source code or just declare my database when I create my blockchain network in the docker compose files? How Fabric communicates with the state db? Any guides or documentation on plugging the database of my choice? What I have to do in order to add my own database?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Hyperledger Fabric there are many "pluggable modules" but not plugs in fact.

For DBs you can choose between LevelDB and CouchDB. Normally CouchDB in serious deployments. Theoretically you should be able to develop your own DB connector, but it would require a huge effort (more taking into account you are just snooping around the technology). It is not prepared for you to plug easily your own DB.

The same can be said about consensus. It is pluggable, but you only can choose between solo, kafka-based and Raft. Even MSP is supposed to be pluggable, but you have only one PKI based implementation.

I would forget about that, unless you got a lot of time and curiosity.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I thought that pugging a database wouldn't be so hard. I found on this page (https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-16406) a developer achieving connection to mongodb. I inspected the code and as I observed, he did some changes in the network folder (I might be wrong).

Comment: You can try, if you want, but as I say it is not a common task. The source code is modular, but it is not thought for a regular developer to plug it easily.